# How to disable java script in internet explorer in nokia lumia 925 in windows phone 8 os?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-mobile

Can anybody tell whether it is possible disable java script in internet explorer in nokia lumia 925 in windows mobile 8 os?
   How can I test web page in internet explorer of windows mobile 8 os for Javascript disabled features ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only block cookies but not javascript.